# How to make a column stretch only on a certain breakpoint?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I learned that I can make a column grow by giving it `col` class:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">This will stretch</div>
    <div class="col-auto"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But what if I want this column to take the full width on small screens and stretch on the same row only on *medium* screens?

Comment: visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: Hey @NishargShah, I tried, but unfortunately couldn't find a solution for this case. I'd appreciate it if you told about me about a certain section to read.

Comment: If you cant solve your problem, come with your problem and code in form of question, we will solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use col-sm and col-sm-auto instead. Then the 2 columns will stack on mobile...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-info">This will stretch</div>
    <div class="col-sm-auto">|</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/KnA4Ivp9Aq